# How do I get the directory of the current script, in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I want to know what the script's directory is. I have a command-line Dart script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to find the script's directory is to use the path package.

```
import "package:path/path.dart" show dirname;
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

main() {
  print(dirname(Platform.script.toString()));
}
```

Put the path package into your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  path: any
```

And be sure to run `pub get` to download and link the path package.

Comment: You asked this question to himself on the October 27, but on October 26 it was announced that the class "Platform" will be transferred into a separate package "package". Maybe you announce about these changes?

Comment: I think that decision was reverted. Platform is in dart:io

Comment: I got the result prefixed with `file://`. Slight improvement for me was to use `Platform.script.path` instead.

Comment: The any version indicator is underused

Comment: what about the file:///, this need to be fixed

Comment: It should be noted that if the script is compiled then Platform.script.path returns the current working directory rather than the actual path to the script.

Answer (score 17):

If you're doing this for a console based app (e.g. in a unit test) and intend to use the output to open a file for reading or writing, it's more helpful to use `Platform.script.path`:

```
import "package:path/path.dart" show dirname, join;
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

main() {
  print(join(dirname(Platform.script.path), 'test_data_file.dat'));
}
```

The result of that command can be used with a `File` object and be opened/read (e.g. if you have a unit test that needs to read/compare sample data, or a console program that needs to open a file relative to the current script for some other reason).

Answer (score 5):

Using Platform.script.path doesn't work in all circumstances.

If your script is compiled or running as a unit test you won't get the expected results.

This is from the dcli project (https://pub.dev/packages/dcli)

If you are using dcli you can call:

```
// absolute path including the script name
DartScript.self.pathToScript;
```

or

```
// just the absolute path to the script's directory
DartScript.self.pathToScriptDirectory;
```

This code works if the script is run via dart <scriptname.dart>, if you compile the script or if you script is a unit test.

Here is the internal implementation.

```
static String get _pathToCurrentScript {
    if (_current == null) {
      final script = Platform.script;

      String _pathToScript;
      if (script.isScheme('file')) {
        _pathToScript = Platform.script.toFilePath();

        if (_isCompiled) {
          _pathToScript = Platform.resolvedExecutable;
        }
      } else {
        /// when running in a unit test we can end up with a 'data' scheme
        if (script.isScheme('data')) {
          final start = script.path.indexOf('file:');
          final end = script.path.lastIndexOf('.dart');
          final fileUri = script.path.substring(start, end + 5);

          /// now parse the remaining uri to a path.
          _pathToScript = Uri.parse(fileUri).toFilePath();
        }
      }

      return _pathToScript;
    } else {
      return _current.pathToScript;
    }
  }

  static bool get _isCompiled =>
      basename(Platform.resolvedExecutable) ==
      basename(Platform.script.path);
```

Comment: this project is awesome

Answer (score 2):

Another (albeit hacky) way to determine the path to the current `.dart` file is to extract the path from the stack trace.

Unlike `Platform.script.path`, this should work with unit tests:

```dart
import 'package:stack_trace/stack_trace.dart' as stacktrace;

/// Returns an absolute path to the caller's `.dart` file.
String currentDartFilePath() => stacktrace.Frame.caller(1).uri.toFilePath();

/// Returns a path to the caller's `.dart` file, relative to the package root.
String currentPackageRelativePath() => stacktrace.Frame.caller(1).library;
```

Note that `stacktrace.Frame.caller(1)` returns the stack frame of the *caller*, so the code above expects that you call `currentDartFilePath()` `currentPackageRelativePath()` and not use `stacktrace.Frame.caller(1).uri.toFilePath()` or `stacktrace.Frame.caller(1).library` directly.

If you want just the directory, you then can perform typical path manipulation operations on the results.