# Get path to current script in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

By running this command

```
flutter test test/widget_tests/rider/home/component/direction_search_fields_test.source.dart
```

I am trying to get this string path "test/widget_tests/rider/home/component/direction_search_fields_test.source.dart" from inside the file itself.

I tried

```
  final dir  = Platform.script.path;
```

But this gives me `/project/path/main.dart`

Comment: Did you try `Script.current.pathToScript` ?

Comment: No let me try that right away

Comment: Which package is Script ?

Comment: This one: https://pub.dev/packages/dcli

Comment: See some of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/19623313/.