# How to get the name of the dart file name?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with Flutter and Dart.

In my project, under /lib directory, I have some dart files and a dart file for every "screen" (or "page", or "activity").

I would need to obtain programmatically the name of the dart file.

If I do the file name request in screen_edituser.dart I would need to obtain "screen_edituser" in a variable.

I tried to use Platform.script but I obtain always "main.dart" whatever the dart file name of the project is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67695494/

Comment: Not the required result:
stacktrace.Frame.caller(1).library
gives
"package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart"

Comment: How are you using it?  `stacktrace.Frame.caller(1).library` gives the path to the *caller*, so if you're using that directly, it won't be what you want.  In that case, you'll want `stacktrace.Frame.caller(0).library` instead.  The code cited at the linked answer assumes that you would be accessing it via `currentDartFilePath()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the directory of the current script, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623313/how-do-i-get-the-directory-of-the-current-script-in-dart)

Comment: stacktrace.Frame.caller(0).library works! Thank you very much. I understood now how caller(1) and caller(0) work.